# Android Studio Kotlin Class doesn't find resources

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, import, android-resources

I have a problem where every single resource isn't found in my kotlin class, like strings, layouts, menus, drawables, and so on. They do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, make sure Android Studio hasn't auto-imported `android.R`. This will change the meaning of `R` from my resources to the library.